# How to execute jar from OS Process Sampler in Linux

Tags: linux, process, operating-system, jmeter

How to execute a jar from OS Process Sampler in Linux? I have the following  [image: attached]sampler which is working fine in Windows. How to execute this OS Process Sampler in Linux?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Linux equivalent would be something like:

- Command: `/bin/bash` (or other [Unix Shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell) which may be different)
- Working directory: like on Windows specify the working folder for the command
- Command parameters:

  - `-c` - according to [bash user manual](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash)

    > **-c string**
    >
    > If the -c option is present, then commands are read from string. If there are arguments after the string, they are assigned to the positional parameters, starting with $0.
  - your actual command. If the command includes spaces or any other special characters which need escaping - either escape them using `\` sign or surround the command with **double** quotation marks

    ```
    ""java -jar myjar.jar param1 param2""
    ```

Remember that in Linux file names are **case sensitive** so change `Java` to `java` as from Linux point of view these 2 are totally different beasts.

**Example Configuration:**

[image: JMeter help execution os process sampler]

**Example Output:**

[image: Os process sampler output]

Check out [How to Run External Commands and Programs Locally and Remotely from JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter) for comprehensive explanation of this and other approaches.

Answer (score 0):

The approach of using `/bin/bash` didn't work for me. Instead, I directly use `java` in command and pass the rest in arguments. Here's the screenshot.

[image]